# What are the legal implications of creators streaming their development?

Tags: legal, intellectual-property

Is there any question of losing ownership of their work if people stream themselves coding? I can understand that streaming modeling, animations, and game design would be fine because even if you see someone do it it will take time to do, but what about code?

Are there worries about other people recording their streams and using their code?
Is there some special case for these games like being open source or non proprietary?

Comment: Not a lawyer but I'm pretty sure the video is clear proof of you creating the code, no?

Comment: @Sidar I would agree, but people can still copy what you produce. From what I understand the law only helps protect you if you have the resources to protect it. It won't protect your IP for you. I think.

Comment: There are at least 3 different questions in this post. Please break them down to different posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vlambeer had a GDC talk about streaming development of their game Nuclear Throne that you can [watch on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-3VFOWrgpU). They streamed some parts of the game that an audience would find interesting. Give it a watch it answers a lot of your questions.

As far an I know they have not had any issues with people stealing their game. They still have the IP of their game and don't have issues.

If someone "stole their code" they would only have small fragments which they could use but what are they really going to do with one class without all the other classes that are needed to make that class work? Without a large chunk of the code or the code for a module you couldn't really make a direct copy it.

As for open source games like [Simutrans](https://www.simutrans.com/en/) and [OpenTTD](https://www.openttd.org/en) they have an open licence so you can use it for whatever you like. The catch is that they still have the Trademark of the game so you can copy and paste the code and change a line of code and sell it but that most likely won't hold up in court under copyright law.

Hope this helps

*I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: This really does help. I was just really interested in the idea of publicizing like this. Like what is the thought behind doing it, and what concerns did they face.